# How to make table like this

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to make table like this:

[image]

But I don't know how can I create row with text "abc".

I have something like this:

```
<table class="porownywarka_cech_opis" width="100" border="1">
     <tr>
        <td class="nazwa">
           <h5 class="Nazwa" style="font-size:12px;">Produkt</h5>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="zdjecie">
           <p>Zdjęcie:</p>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="cena_netto">
           <p>Cena netto:</p>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="cena_brutto">
           <p>Cena brutto:</p>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        Here I don't know how to make this
     </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you can use `colspan`

Comment: Seeking something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/9567thv1/2/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `colspan` attribute. Add a second `<td>` to each of the rows except the last one.

### HTML

```
<table class="porownywarka_cech_opis" width="100" border="1">
<tr>
    <td class="nazwa">
         <h5 class="Nazwa" style="font-size:12px;">Produkt</h5>

    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="zdjecie">
        <p>Zdjęcie:</p>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cena_netto">
        <p>Cena netto:</p>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cena_brutto">
        <p>Cena brutto:</p>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">abc</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
td {
width: 100px;
border: 0;
background: #aaa;
}
td:nth-child(2n) {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvgbr0n2/)

Answer (score 0):

You must add table data tags in between table row tags. Also, set your table data to `colspan="2"`

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Here I don't know how to make this</td>
</tr>
```

Hope it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2spafL4q/

HTML markup:

```
<table class="porownywarka_cech_opis" width="100" border="1">
  <thead>
      <th> </th><th> </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="nazwa">
        <h5 class="Nazwa" style="font-size:12px;">Produkt</h5>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="zdjecie">
        <p>Zdjęcie:</p>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cena_netto">
        <p>Cena netto:</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cena_brutto">
        <p>Cena brutto:</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="abc" colspan="2">  
        Here I don't know how to make this
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS rules:

```
table {
    width: 400px;
}
th {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
td {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
}
td.abc {
    text-align: center;
}
```